# What are the factors considered in the development of the video game controllers over the years?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, design

What are the ergonomics taken into account in evolution of video game controller over the years.

[image: controller]

Comment: How hands, fingers and thumbs work compared to a price point.

Comment: And in the N64's case, alien hands.